# Pruning specific duplicate rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of purchase orders that's updated daily (it's a large list).  As orders are complete, they are added to the list as "closed" instead of "open", but the "open" entry stays on the list.  I want to find duplicate entries (duplicate rows of data except open/closed status) and remove the duplicate "Open" entry.

I know how to use the RemoveDuplicates method, but I suspect that method does not have the ability to do what I want.  I can do this by looping through the Open orders to find duplicates, but I'm assuming there's a slightly cleaner more efficient method.  Also order numbers are recycled so Order Number and Date have to match for it to be a duplicate order.

The data is structured like this:

```
    A        |    B     |      C
Order Number |   Date   |   Closed/Open
--------------------------------------
    1        |    1     |     Open
    2        |    1     |     Open
    1        |    2     |     Open
    4        |    2     |     Open
    1        |    2     |     Open
    1        |    1     |     Closed
```

In the above case, the first and last rows have duplicate columns A and B.  In this case, I want to remove only the one that's "Open" and keep the other.

Does anyone know of a slick way of doing this? or should I just loop throw all the open orders to see if any are closed?

Comment: If there is a one to one relationship based on Order Number and Date to the Open/Closed.  Sort column C then use remove duplicates for all three based on the first two columns.  Remove Duplicates keeps the first and removes all others.  So if you sort the closed to the top it will keep the closed and remove the open.

Comment: Hello JayWill,  create a `Scripting.Dictionary`which has all the closed  orders, drop your purchase data into an array, and loop through the array searching for matches with your dictionary.